# Message showing You are not authorized to access this page

Tags: users

I have checked access content permission for both anonymous as well as authenticated users. But when i access a node content without logging in it shows the message "You are not authorized to access this page". Could i reset permission to default permissions. Any idea what is going wrong

Comment: Did you pubish the node?

Comment: Do you want to simply reset permissions to their default or know what went wrong? If both, it should probably be 2 questions, as answers to both problems are totally unrelated